# How automatically add to version control new content in a new directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-add

I created a new `fonts` directory under `app/assets/` and added to version control the `fonts` directory with `git add fonts`. 
Usually, when I create or include a new file in any place of my project folder already under version control, this new file is automatically added to the index and reported by `git status` under section `untracked files.`
However I noticed that every new file I include in `fonts` is not automatically included to version control. Instead if I git add the directory already containing files, also those files will be git added. How can I fix this? 
 
Is there a way to create and add to version control a new directory so that every new file included is automatically added to version control as well?

Comment: Just run `git add -A`?

Comment: I thought that `git add fonts` would make the job but it seems it does not. Running `git add fonts` and then `git add -A` seems a repetition. Is there any command like `git add -A` for a single object, a command that add the new directory and all its content to the index? I take `git add -A` as a last resort.

Comment: After chatting with you, I'm really no clearer on your question and don't think your question (nor my answer) will benefit anyone else. Voting to close.

Comment: It would be nicer not let me wait 30 minutes at the chat room. I suspect that `git add newdirectory` should be run when the directory is not empty so all new files would be added recursively to version control. I would check my idea after a sleep and probably add myself an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise a repository with `git init` followed by `git add -A` and the first commit, you create a Git directory which is a copy of your repository. The repository is also the working directory. 
When you modify files in your working directory, these files are staged for commit in the staging area. You can then commit these changes and 'update' the Git directory.

When you add a new file in the working directory, this file is also staged by Git for commit in section 'untracked files', because it is new and there is no trace of it in the Git directory.

Only new files are automatically staged by Git. 
 New empty directories are ignored and also later removed by Git (see below). 
So when you add a new empty directory and try to commit, Git would warn you that that commit would not make any change and suggest to use the `--allow-empty` option if you instead want to keep anyway that useless commit.

Instead, after creating the new directory, you should put some file in it.
 In fact, usually to let Git keep an empty directory in the working and Git directories, it is necessary to add inside that directory an empty hidden file named `.keep`

This time `git add fonts` will succeed, because it will add recursively all the files inside the `fonts` directory to the staging area. The next commit will store that new snapshot permanently to your Git directory. Alternatively, if this commit is not meaningful, you can keep working on your working directory and when time comes, as suggested by Carpetsmoker, do a `git add -A` followed by your commit.

If you replenish your new directory with files but do not add the `.keep` empty hidden file, later on if you remove all font files inside the `fonts` directory the directory itself will be removed.